# Need help installing PHPunit with composer

Tags: phpunit, composer-php

I am trying to install PHPunit using composer and I keep on getting the same error message every time I try to install.

Anyone familiar with this issue or know how to fix this. Thanks in advance!

Problem 1
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 4.6.*@dev -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[4.6.x-dev].
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.6.x-dev requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ~3.0 -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind guys! I specified the exact version "phpunit/phpunit": "4.4.0" and it worked. Thanks!